# how to do addition of textbox values(Integers) on Lost Focus Property and Show it in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have many `Textboxes` and I want to Add the Values(Sum of Integers) of `Textboxes` and Show it in a `textblock` on `Lost Focus Property`.... 
For example:

I fill a `Textbox` with integer `5`, the value of `Textblock` Changes to 5.... And after that I fill another `Textbox` with 4... `Textblock` changes to 9`.`

I short How can I bind single TextBlock to Multiple Textboxes with Lost_Focus Property?

Please Answer I cannot find it anywhere on Web.

Comment: you can bind all the textboxes to the same event handler also what you are trying to do is not difficult at all.. lastly.. why don't you show us what you have tried..this is not a coding service and also we are not here to do you homework for you.. please provide coded efforts `TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)` there's a hint

Comment: i am not doing homework... I am a beginner Programmer. Just asked a Simple Question Hoping Someone will Help... But no Worries. Thanks by the way.

Comment: beginner or not.. it's amazing how many individuals find there way here to `Stackoverflow but can't seem to execute a simple Google Search` meaning there are so many free C# tutorials online you should show some effort beginner or not.. respectfully speaking

Comment: i have Tried searching it on Google... But i couldn't find it.... What is your problem... If you cannot answer then Please do not interfere. Someone who is willing to help will help.... After all you don't own StackoverFlow.

Comment: I can definitely answer and with your poor attitude I doubt you will get any help.. other will see this and surely ask What have you tired.. good luck

Comment: hahaha Another man Just answered me.... Shame you didn't knew the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Dear,
 In this way you can easily add textboxes in textblock
keep

```
  int sum=0;
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(_1.Text);
     Add.Text = sum.ToString();
  }
  private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(_2.Text);
      Add.Text = sum.ToString();
  }
```