# How to do calculations on various textboxes and show them in textbox on lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to get my little program to do some calculations.

So far I have 15 textboxes, named TxtPP(followed by product type),so i got TxtPPproduct1, TxtPPproduct2 etc....
At the bottom of the form I have a disabled textbox which shows the total of all the above textboxes.

I don't want to use a button to do the calculations, I want this to be done every time a value is added to one of the textboxes (so on `LostFocus`).

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: didn't you ask this question before.. you need to look at events such as onChange, or OnLeave, have you looked at all of the events that are associated with the `TextBox` is this the same as your previously posted code here..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884542/how-to-do-addition-of-textbox-valuesintegers-on-lost-focus-property-and-show-i?noredirect=1#comment46030997_28884542

Comment: also if  you want to sum up all the textboxes and throw the totals in a different textbox.. then google how to use `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)` then from there you will need to check the type if the control IS TextBox, if it is then from there you need to check is values are of Int

Comment: anyone can downvote a question based on several factors with  that being said.. I think it would help if you can show some code in regards to what Event you are using / wiring up for all 15 Textboxes.. hopefully you assigned them all except the textboxt that will hold the totals, are sharing the same event handler..

Comment: @MethodMan He tagged with binding, why suggest UI-manipulation methods?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET it would be nice to see exactly how the OP is doing the Binding in the Xaml now since you seem to be a mind reader perhaps you can answer the code for the OP

Comment: @MethodMan Was working on it as you typed :) answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to take advantage of `set` being a *method*, which means you can raise `PropertyChanged` for other properties than just the one you are in.

First you need each source textbox to be bound. To get it to update the source on losing input focus, set the [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) to `LostFocus` for example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstSourceValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

Now, in the setter for the bound member, you need to raise `PropertyChanged` for the *derived* value as well, something like:

```
public double FirstSourceValue
{
    get { return firstSourceValue; }
    set
    {
         firstSourceValue = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged(); //Notify for this property
         NotifyPropertyChanged("DerivedValue"); //Notify for the other one
    }
}
```

And the derived value property just returns the result of the calculation:

```
public DerivedValue
{
    get { return FirstSourceValue + SecondSourceValue; }
}
```

Now you can bind your disabled text box to it, and it will update whenever the other text boxes do:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding DerivedValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```